# jQuery treeTable with PersistJS

Tags: jquery, cookies, persist, treetable

I'm sure this as as basic as it gets, but either way... now needs to be asked snce I can't get it to work. I've implemented jQuery treeTable just fine, and have now come to the part whereby the tree state needs to be kept open on page refresh (actually on a revisit to the page after popping off to another). For this, treeTable have a built-in setting for persist.js - However, there's insufficient documentation on how the two talk to each other. I also don't think I've initiated the persist.js properly.

Head elements are;

```
<script src="jquery_1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="persist-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()  {
  store = new Persist.Store('treeTablePers');
});
</script>

<script src="jquery.treeTable.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<link href="jquery.treeTable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()  {
$("#resourceTable").treeTable({
persist: true,
persistStoreName: "treeTablePers"
});
});
</script>
```

The tree state simply needs to re-open on refresh, with the same branches open. I'm fairly sure I don't need to change the html, other than the head scripts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The above doesn't work... So what have I done wrong and how do I get it to work please. "The tree state simply needs to re-open on refresh, with the same branches open."

Comment: Please give more clarification on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never: there is a now good example on how to use the treetable plugin (version 3.0) with PersistJS at https://github.com/jughead/jquery-treetable-ajax-persist. The main file of interest is https://github.com/jughead/jquery-treetable-ajax-persist/blob/master/src/javascripts/jquery.treetable-ajax-persist.js.